# making one of the select dropdowns required

Tags: php, html

i have searched all over and i cannot find a good answer for this.
I have 3 dropdowns where user can select a date (all 3 are populated from DB). I need 3 becouse user can apply to all 3 at the same time. Now what i need to do is make at lease one required. Any ideas about that? Also the names are different since i am sending this to php function mail() to send all the data to my mail.

```
      <select   name="prijava_okp" id="prijava_okp" >
            <option value="" selected="selected">Online klinični primeri </option>;
            <?php 
            include("config.php");
            session_start();
            if (!$db) {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($db));
            }
            $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT ID_TECAJA, DATUM, HOUR FROM razpisani_tecaji WHERE STATUS ='odprt' AND ST_ODPRTIH_MEST>0 AND VRSTA=1");
            while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
                $row['DATUM'] = new DateTime($row['DATUM']);
                $dateFormated =  $row['DATUM']->format('d.m.Y');

                echo "<option value='" . $row['ID_TECAJA'] . "'>" . $dateFormated," ","ob"," ", $row['HOUR'] . "</option>";

            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <select   name="prijava_ops" id="prijava_ops" >
            <option value="" selected="selected">Online priprave na strokovni izpit</option>;
            <?php 
            include("config.php");
            session_start();
            if (!$db) {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($db));
            }
            $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT ID_TECAJA, DATUM, HOUR FROM razpisani_tecaji WHERE STATUS ='odprt' AND ST_ODPRTIH_MEST>0 AND VRSTA=2");
            while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
                $row['DATUM'] = new DateTime($row['DATUM']);
                $dateFormated =  $row['DATUM']->format('d.m.Y');

                echo "<option value='" . $row['ID_TECAJA'] . "'>" . $dateFormated," ","ob"," ", $row['HOUR'] . "</option>";

            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <select   name="prijava_ods" id="prijava_ods" >
            <option value="" selected="selected">Online delavnice za študente medicine</option>;
            <?php 
            include("config.php");
            session_start();
            if (!$db) {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($db));
            }
            $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT ID_TECAJA, DATUM, HOUR FROM razpisani_tecaji WHERE STATUS ='odprt' AND ST_ODPRTIH_MEST>0 AND VRSTA=3");
            while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
                $row['DATUM'] = new DateTime($row['DATUM']);
                $dateFormated =  $row['DATUM']->format('d.m.Y');

                echo "<option value='" . $row['ID_TECAJA'] . "'>" . $dateFormated," ","ob"," ", $row['HOUR'] . "</option>";

            }
            ?>
        </select><br><br>
```

Comment: For start, you can tabulate your code properly.

Comment: Firstly, presumably the 3 `select` elements are in the same page, so why do you have so much unnecessary repetition? I suggest you look up the DRY (Don't repeat yourself) principle because your code incorporated some bad practices. Regarding your question: please include an outline of your current validation functions so we can see what you are currently doing, and see if you need server-side (in PHP) validation only, or also need to check it on client-side. Client-side validation would require javascript, but you haven't tagged this question as javascript or jquery.

Comment: Hi @FluffyKitten , yes they are all on the same page? How am i repeating?? I have in each dropdown different <php> which needs to be executed. Different select from! All i need is to make one of the dropdowns required filelds. I know in radio buttons, you give the radios same name and then give one of them required and thats it. However i need 3 different names here also.

Comment: You are repeating code each time that is only needed once, e.g. you are including config.php 3 times, starting the session 3 times, checking the same database connection 3 times etc. Also, you haven't included your current server-side validation so we can show you how to add the check for the selects there. And you also haven't said if you need client-side javascript validation as well as the PHP validation.

Comment: @user8585307 you are repeating yourself, not in the sense you are making three identical dropdowns; rather your code is very repetitive and wordy. For instance your query is basically the same, expect for the last part; that's not necessary... You can create one function which will take in a query, and spit out the `option` values. It's just bad practice because each time you need to update 1 thing, now you have to update 2 more things. Down the road that will cause a lot of headache, listen to @FluffyKitten

Comment: Hi @FluffyKitten, i will look into things you are mentoning as soon as possible. I am still learning all of this so thank you for any tips. Will post update as soon as i have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### CLIENT-SIDE

Use some Javascript for your form; just check to make sure that all three are equals to empty. If so, then return `false`; this will prevent the form from being submitted, if the user, then, selects a single field the condition is no longer `true` and the form can be submitted.

NOTE: I am using jquery; but this can easily be transcribed to Javascript Vanilla.

```js
$('#submit').on('click', function() {

  // create variables
  var select1 = $('#select1');
  var select2 = $('#select2');
  var select3 = $('#select3');
  
  // validate form
  if ( select1.val() == '' && select2.val() == '' && select3.val() == '') {
    
    alert('You need to select at least one value!');
    return false; // do not submit
    
  }
  else
  {
    return true; // submit form
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="dropdown" action="" method="post">

  <select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="value2">Value2</option>
    <option value="value3">Value3</option>
    <option value="value4">Value4</option>
  </select>
  <select name="select2" id="select2">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="value2">Value2</option>
    <option value="value3">Value3</option>
    <option value="value4">Value4</option>
  </select>
  <select name="select3" id="select3">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="value2">Value2</option>
    <option value="value3">Value3</option>
    <option value="value4">Value4</option>
  </select>

  <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

### SERVER-SIDE

You can, and should, also validate your form on your server side; this will prevent the user from bypassing whatever parameters you have set - to a certain extant.

I will continue with the same concept, have an `if` condition which will only return allow the code to run only if the user has selected at least one value. If all three are empty then it will echo an error and will stop the code from running.

Now if the condition is false; then that means that 1 or more `select` values have been selected and the user is cleared to continue...

```
// first check for $_POST
if ( isset( $_POST ) )
{
    // create variables
    // filter them for any html tags
    $prijava_okp = htmlentities( $_POST['prijava_okp'] );
    $prijava_ops = htmlentities( $_POST['prijava_ops'] );
    $prijava_ods = htmlentities( $_POST['prijava_ods'] );

    // now check to see if all three are empty
    if ( empty( $prijava_okp ) && empty( $prijava_ops ) && empty( $prijava_ods ) )
    {
        // if they are all three empty `exit` the script
        // or use `header` to go back to the form
        echo 'You have to select at least one or more fields!';
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        // ... run your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: From my understanding of the question, that's not going to work - it will force the user to select a value in a specific dropdown. The user can select *any* one of the 3 dropdowns at a minimum.

Comment: As @FluffyKitten wrote it wont work. Read a question again. I need a user to select 1/3 but if i put req to one than user will need to always select that one, which is something i do not want.

Comment: @user8585307 I have updated my answer... I hope this helps; now the user has to select at least one value before submitting form.

Comment: And the server-side validation? Client-side validation is only for the benefit of users. Client-side validation can easily be bypassed, so server-side validation is always required to ensure the integrity of the data before processing it.

Comment: Hold on ... -_- @FluffyKitten

Comment: You might want to wait until the OP shows us their existing server-side validation code to see how the currently process it, otherwise you might just end up rewriting a lot of what they do already. That is, assuming they do any, which I'm not so sure about...:) If they don't, then its up to them to at least make an attempt at it themselves first.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I have just written up a quick check; same as my client-side, but with PHP code in the server-side... like you said, can't really give him much since I don't know what he's already doing in the backend; but this should give him a quick overall idea ;)

Comment: Looks good... not much more you can do for them without specific details :)

Comment: Thou art welcome :P You've more patience than I do with vague questions, I prefer to make them work out the specifics first themselves.

Comment: @FluffyKitten 'Tis true; but not long ago I was very similar, and if it were not for very patience programmers I would never be in the same position; I had much help, and I enjoy giving back; as well as the challenge ;) that is always fun

Comment: Same here, but my personal "teaching" approach is to encourage them to at least think about the problem first, because it helps build problem-solving skills. And I actually thought I was being quite patient with the OP this time... :) Between the 2 different approaches, we'll sort them out! Keep up the good work :)